# How to add extra parameter in with condition in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to add extra parameter **type** in with condition.

I have no **type** column in matches table.

```
$list = self::where('id', $user->id);
$list = $list->with(['matches'=>function($q) use($user) {
    $q = $q->where('user_id', $user->id);
    $q = $q->with(['touser'=>function($q1) {
        $q1 = $q1->select('id', 'name', 'email', 'user_image', 'is_active', 'is_profile_completed');
    }]);
    $q->select('id', 'uuid', 'user_id', 'to_user_id');
}]);
$list = $list->get();
```

Expeacted Out put is:

```
"matches": [
    {
        "id": 2,
        "uuid": "dedescvdf",
        "user_id": 128,
        "type": 1,
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "uuid": "dedescvdf",
        "user_id": 128,
        "type": 1,
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value of "type" is static you can try something like this:

Add this line (import) at the begging of the file:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

Then:

```
$q->select('id', 'uuid', 'user_id', 'to_user_id', DB::raw("1 as 'type'"));
```

Comment: I am getting error..

Comment: @kirtan please post the error

Comment: @kirtan Answer updated